# Create a mixin for class Meta in ModelForm

Tags: django

**Django==1.11.3**

The code below seems to violate DRY principle.
But I fail to create a mixin to generalize the three strings with:

1. exclude;
2. from_date
3. through_date.

Could you give me a kick here?

```
class BatchDateInputForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BatchDateInput
        exclude = []

        widgets = {
            'user': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'from_date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=get_years()),
            'through_date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=get_years()),
        }


class FrameDateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = FrameDate
            exclude = []

            widgets = {
                'frame': forms.HiddenInput(),
                'from_date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=get_years()),
                'through_date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=get_years())
            }
```

Comment: I would argue that your code is fine as it is, using mixins here would only obfuscate how your forms are built up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but I think this should work:

```py
def get_widgets():
    return {
        'user': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'from_date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=get_years()),
        'through_date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=get_years()),
    }


class BatchDateInputForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BatchDateInput
        exclude = []
        widgets = get_widgets()


class FrameDateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = FrameDate
        exclude = []
        widgets = get_widgets()
```

Comment: BTW: https://thevaluable.dev/dry-principle-cost-benefit-example/ ;)

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on type of attributes you are trying to overload. Here is a way to achive this without using metaclasses, it is not as pretty, but will do the job

```
class BaseMeta:
    exclude = []

    widgets = {
        'from_date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=get_years()),
        'through_date': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=get_years())
    }

class BatchDateInputForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        model = BatchDateInput

        widgets = BaseMeta.widgets.copy()
        widgets.update({
            'user': forms.HiddenInput(),
        })


class FrameDateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        model = FrameDate

        widgets = BaseMeta.widgets.copy()
        widgets.update({
            'frame': forms.HiddenInput(),
        })
```

**Note** you will have to always rember to copy other `dict` attributes for `BaseMeta` otherwise it will update `dict` attribute on all subclasses